# Set umask on PBS-job

Tags: perl, file-permissions, pbs, umask

In the process of writing a Perl-script to submit PBS-jobs, I noticed that the output-files are only usable by the owner (rw-------). After some research, I found that you can put `#PBS -W umask=002` in the job-script to make it accessible for others.

Perl:

```
my $client = PBS::Client->new();

my $wd    = $dir_temp;
my $name  = "demultiplex";
my $queue = "default";
my $wallt = "72:00:00";
my $job_demultiplex = PBS::Client::Job -> new(
    wd    => $wd,
    queue => $queue,
    name  => $name,
    wallt => $wallt,
    cmd   => "perl ".$script_directory."demultiplex.pl ".$dir_in." 2>"."demultiplex_error.log 1>"."demultiplex_output.log"
);
```

This Perlscript creates the following job:

```
#!/bin/sh

#PBS -N demultiplex
#PBS -d /store/www/labresults_QC/small_rna_sequence_analyser/data/data_temp/BGI_pilot
#PBS -q default
#PBS -l nodes=1
#PBS -l walltime=72:00:00
#PBS -W umask=002                 <---

perl /store/www/labresults_QC/small_rna_sequence_analyser/scripts/demultiplex.pl /store/www/labresults_QC/small_rna_sequence_analyser/data/data_input/BGI_pilot 2>demultiplex_error.log 1>demultiplex_output.log
```

Is there a possibility to pass the indicated line (`<---`) to the job from the Perlscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [current codebase](https://metacpan.org/source/KWMAK/PBS-Client-0.10/lib/PBS/Client.pm#L272), no.  You'd have to open a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PBS-Client) to the [PBS::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/PBS%3a%3aClient) module and request the feature.  Accompany it with a patch - that might help.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case, since I didn't find anything about it. Thanks anyway!